# Utilizing readlines() correctly

Tags: python

I am attempting to use readlines in my program but I keep getting an error when I utilize it. I am not sure why, can anyone help?

```
try:
    filename = input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to examine: ")
    S = open("filename","r")
except:
    print("Cannot open " + filename + "!")

Slines = S.readlines()
li = len(Slines)
words = 0
chars = 0
for item in Slines:
    splitem = item.split()
    words += (len(splitem) - 2)
    chars += (len(item) - 2)


print("In " + filename + "There were:")
print(str(li) + " lines")
print(str(words) + " words")
print(str(chars) + " characters")
S.close()
```

Comment: "I keep getting an error" – care to share?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Change `S = open("filename","r")` to `S = open(filename,"r")` Your are trying to open a file called `filename` rather than the variable which contains the users input.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
S = open("filename","r")
```

To:

```
S = open(filename, "r")
```